# Macbook Air Infinite Boot Chime

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Macbook Air "Core i5" 1.6 13" (Early 2015)

No water damage and never been dropped and sadly out of warranty and without Apple Care.

It started to crash intermittently and then started to reboot. Sometimes it would reboot and work for a while but then it started rebooting every few minutes.

I reset the VRAM & SMC and now I am stuck with a black screen and infinite boot chime.

I get one clean boot chime and then infinite distorted chimes every 2-3 seconds .. this isn't the standard 3 or 9 chimes which suggests Motherboard or RAM .. it is infinite! It doesn't stop until I hold in the Power Button.

So I popped the MBA open, knowing that the RAM couldn't be easily addressed, but considered pulling the battery for a period of time, re-seating the SSD etc etc. Nothing seemed to change.

However when I remove the video connector cable (the slightly angled one in top left corner with black tab) the infinite chime goes away and I get a standard single one chime startup. Obviously I have a black screen at this point and cannot see if the system is starting correctly.

So next step, pressing Shift Key does not put it in Safe Mode - it just hangs on Apple Logo with progress bar, however holding Command + V loads Verbose Mode and then all starts correctly, unfortunately without wifi at this point.

System Information shows the correct RAM Slots, Sizes & Status on both is OK

But rebooting causes the Infinite Chime to return.

So everything works fine in Verbose Mode, but can't Enter Regular Mode, Safe Boot, Diagnostics or Recovery Mode. How would one perform a fresh install from Verbose Mode when Wi-Fi is disabled?

Any ideas ?

Comment: The problem may be in Flash Memory that corrupted. You might need to replace it and can fix your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately Flash Memory cannot be replaced in a Macbook Air as it is soldered to the motherboard, however all system stats show the Flash Memory is fine ... My initial thoughts are more with a graphics card as removing the Monitor cable seems to cease the chimes and loading into Verbose mode everything is working perfectly .. Surely corrupted Flash Memory would still be corrupted in Verbose mode ?

Comment: Verbose mode isn’t anything but *verbose*.  All it does is show text during the boot process. Other than that, It’s the “regular” mode. This however, sounds like hardware.  Try booting while hold D for Apple Diagnostics

Comment: I get that but if i continue to hold Command + V the system loads perfectly after verbose mode .. however rebooting goes back to my initial problem .. Can't enter any other mode, including Single User, Recovery or Diagnostics .. The only command that works is Verbose which then loads the system fine, but without Wi-Fi, so i assumed that this was also some secondary form of Safe Boot as it fails to load the Wi-Fi driver

Comment: So this could be my problem i guess .. I assumed that Wi-FI was being disabled by Verbose, similar to how Windows Loads in Safe Mode .. When i hover over the Wi-FI icon it says no hardware installed .. could there be any connection ?

Comment: It’s entirely plausible that a faulty AirPort card is to blame.  Try Diagnostic Mode as described above.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions, but Diagnostics hangs at 1 minute remaining as do most other Startup Commands .. Ridiculous as it sounds the only way i can get into the machine is by Command & V .. after all verbose text machine loads and runs perfectly ..